# How to turn a script into a function

Tags: python

I have a script that I wrote earlier and am now trying to create a main page to run this script and others. I understand I have to turn this into a function then call it when nesicary but I am having some trouble in the function portion. Any help and advice is greatly appreciated. Below is the script I am referencing.

```
#A Python math script
a = float(raw_input("Enter the first number: "))
b = float(raw_input("Enter the second number: "))

print "Your answer is: ",(a*b)
```

Comment: You really should take a look at: http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/functions.html

Comment: Or the current documentation:  http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions   (the v1.5 documentation is over 12 years old!)

Comment: You are right. I've accidentaly posted a link to a very outdated documentation. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you need is to make this code into a script then save this into a file say multiply.py

In this file you would have for example:

```
def main():
    a = float(raw_input("Enter the first number: "))
    b = float(raw_input("Enter the second number: "))

    print "Your answer is: ",(a*b)

main()
```

then you can call this by: python multiply.py

You can also make this into an importable module by including this line which checks whether or not this module is executing as a main program or not. And therefore it will not run if its imported by another module.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want the function to do? If you want it to still take input and output from the prompt, you can just do

```
def myfunc():
    a = float(raw_input("Enter the first number: "))
    b = float(raw_input("Enter the second number: "))

    print "Your answer is: ",(a*b)
```

Answer (score -1):

if for some unknown reason you can't rewrite it as a function as shown by others you could do

A Python math script

```
#script.py
a = float(raw_input("Enter the first number: "))
b = float(raw_input("Enter the second number: "))

print "Your answer is: ",(a*b)
```

Another script

```
def func():

    execfile("script.py")
```